# how to save image base 64 as a file

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using ionic2: I want to upload an image from the gallery, crop it and send it to a server.

```
uploadImage(): Promise<any> {
    var status = 'upload';
    return new Promise(resolve =>
    {
        const options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            sourceType: 2,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            allowEdit: true
        }
        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
            // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
            // If it's base64:
            this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64",imageData;
            console.log("imaaage ",this.base64Image);
            resolve(this.base64Image);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("error")
        });
    });
}
```

the problem is that: I want `destinationType` to be `FILE_URL` to send it, at the same time I want it to be `DATA_URL` to display it to the user.
what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: you can display using FILE_URL..

Comment: @SurajRao how, can you give me a link describes it?

Comment: you can set the src to `img src` tag in html...